# Fom missing 1 required positional argument: 'request' in form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to get my form work using previous stackoverflow answers and google but nothing seems to work for me.

I have a model Project and a project team and I would like the user to be able to choose from one of the teams that he created and link it to the project.

I am using a custom user called MyUser

that is my form in order to select a team:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from registration.models import MyUser
from .models import Project, Team
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

class EditSelectTeam(forms.Form):

    team_choice = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, queryset=None)

    def __init__(self, User, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditSelectTeam, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['team_choice'].queryset = Team.objects.all().filter(team_hr_admin = request.User)
```

my views:

```
def TeamSelect(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        select_form = EditSelectTeam(request.user, request.POST)
        if select_form.is_valid():
            print('sucess')
        else:
            print('Fail')

    else:
        select_form = EditSelectTeam(request)
    return render(request,'link_project.html',
                            {'select_form':select_form })
```

If in my form I put `request.User` I get the error in my view that :

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

If I do not put user in my `__init__` I get the form but when I click POST I get the error

```
AttributeError: 'MyUser' object has no attribute 'user'
```

Comment: else:`select_form = EditSelectTeam()` try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `__init__` method takes `User` and `request`,

```
def __init__(self, User, request, *args, **kwargs):
```

but you only ever pass one of these to the form:

```
select_form = EditSelectTeam(request.user, request.POST)
...
select_form = EditSelectTeam(request)
```

I would change the `__init__` method to just take `user` (lowercase),

```
def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    super(EditSelectTeam, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['team_choice'].queryset = Team.objects.all().filter(team_hr_admin=user)
```

then change the view to always pass `request.user`.

```
select_form = EditSelectTeam(request.user, request.POST)
...
select_form = EditSelectTeam(request.user)
```

Comment: With the edits I get :__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Comment: Ok got it ! it worked thx you ;) What represent request exactly ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by 'what represent request exactly?'. Your form doesn't really need the request, it just needs the logged in user. So I removed the `request` from the form, and then passed the logged in user (which you access as `request.user`) to the form in the view. The only other change was to use lowercase `user`, so that it doesn't clash with the model `User`.